# Create markup styling in a string based on given hex color codes

Tags: javascript, php, html

#### Trivia

As you know, colors inside CSS can be represented with RGB model (`rgb(255, 255, 255)`) or with hex codes (`#ffffff` or `#fff`), which is generally shorter. Both examples represent white color.

#### Question

Because of a shorter syntax, we can easily embed/insert hex codes inside a string. The function I want would **delete** these hex codes (represented as `#xxxxxx` (anywhere) in a given string) and convert them into markup tag, which colors a string from **where the color was removed** to **the end of the string** or **until a new hex code is found** (which would override previous color).

#### Examples

Bullet point represents **input**, followed by the **output** within a code block.

- `Jo#ff0000hn`

  ```
  Jo<span style="color:#ff0000">hn</span>
  ```
- `Ash#ffff00ley`

  ```
  Ash<span style="color:#ffff00">ley</span>
  ```
- `D#00ffffarth#ffff00Vader`

  ```
  D<span style="color:#00ffff">arth</span><span style="color:#ffff00">Vader</span>
  ```

  or

  ```
  D<span style="color:#00ffff">arth<span style="color:#ffff00">Vader</span></span>
  ```
- `A #ff0000very #0000ffcomplex #0fc0fcexa#ff0000mple`

  ```
  A <span style="color:#ff0000">very</span> <span style="color:#0000ff">complex</span> <span style="color:#0fc0fc">exa</span><span style="color:#ff0000">mple</span>
  ```

#### Snippet

This is how it should look in HTML.

```html
- Jo#ff0000hn<br>
Jo<span style="color:#ff0000">hn</span><br><br>

- Ash#00ff00ley<br>
Ash<span style="color:#00ff00">ley</span><br><br>

- D#00ffffarth#0000ffVader<br>
D<span style="color:#00ffff">arth</span><span style="color:#0000ff">Vader</span><br>
D<span style="color:#00ffff">arth<span style="color:#0000ff">Vader</span></span><br>
<i>Note: Both are same, the first one may be more syntactically correct.</i><br><br>

- A #ff0000very #0000ffcomplex #0fc0fcexa#ff0000mple<br>
A <span style="color:#ff0000">very</span> <span style="color:#0000ff">complex</span> <span style="color:#0fc0fc">exa</span><span style="color:#ff0000">mple</span><br>
<br>
```

#### Tests

Both codes below work fine for my needs, but they have a few problems:

- They don't work with shorter syntax (like `#fff`)
- Consecutive colors causes only the last color to be detected (`#ffffff#000000#ff0000` would detect only `#ff0000`)

**PHP** (Thanks to @Maxim Krizhanovsky)

```php
function colorize($string) {
    return preg_replace('/(#[0-9a-f]{6})([a-z]+)/i', '<span style="color: $1;">$2</span>', $string);
}

echo colorize("Darth#ff0000Vader");
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function colorize(string) {
    return string.replace(/(#[0-9a-f]{6})(\w+)/gi, `<span style="color: $1;">$2</span>`)
}

console.log(colorize("Darth#ff0000Vader"));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Question is also unclear to me.

Comment: I tried preg_replace but that only removes hex color codes.

Comment: @GTX: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @GTX: The reason you're seeing so many downvotes is not so much lack of clarity, but no clear effort on your part.  It helps a great deal on Stack Overflow if, when looking for assistance, you provide code showing what you've tried first.  This both clarifies your problem and shows to the community that you're not just looking for people to write code for you, but to interact, learn, and help out others who may have the same problem in the future.  Hope you find your time here educational!  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You need a regular expression, something like:

```
$string = 'Jo#ff0000hn'; 
echo preg_replace('/(#[0-9a-f]{1,6})([a-z]+)/i', '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>', $string);
```

Comment: #F is not a valid hexadecimal color.. You need to match 3 or 6

Comment: This completely removes my text. I want to color the text after hex color code.

Comment: Thanks, that works but if I use this string: -rG-GT#ff0000X#ffffff~ that returns -rG-GTXf~ (colors work, it's just this "f" after X)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names don't contain hashtags and the color is always formatted as #000000.

```
$name='Jo#ff0000hn';
$p=strpos($name,'#');
$color = substr($name,$p,7);
$newcolor='<span style="color:'.substr($name,$p,7).'">';
$name = str_replace($color,$newcolor,$name).'</span>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work quite well as it should. Some colors are not converted, and if I have 2 colors, second one doesn't get converted. Like: -rG-GT#ff0000X#ffffff~ converts it into -rG-GT"X#ffffff~ ("X#ffffff~ is colored in red)

Comment: This code does everything you asked for. If you have more specific needs, you should provide us with more details and maybe some code.

Comment: `function convertHexToColor($string){
 $arr = explode("#",$string);
 $str = "";
 foreach ($arr as $val) {
  $mtc = preg_match('/([0-9a-f]{1,6})/',$val);
  $clr = "ffffff";
  if ($mtc) {
   $clr = substr($val,0,5);
   $val = substr($val,6);
  }
  $str = $str.'<font color="#'.$clr.'">'.$val.'</font>';
 }
 return $str;
}`

If I have name -rG-R3#9a2cd8birth<3 it only shows colored birth<3